# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Token' not found in

Tags: php, token

I'm started to study the PHP OOP and was trying to create a login system. Got the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Token' not found in ..login/register.php on line
>   61.

See the listings below:

**register.php**

```
    <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()){
    $validate = new Validate(); 
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' =>array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
            ),
        'password' =>array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
            ),
        'password_again' =>array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
            ),
        'name' =>array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
            )
        ));
  if($validation->passed()){
    echo 'Passed';

   }else {

    foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
        echo $error, '<br>';

    }

}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">

<div class="field">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type ="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo Input::get('username'); ?>" autocomplete="off">

</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="password">Choose a password</label>
<input type ="password" name="password" id="password"> 
</div>

<div class="field">
<label for="password_again">Enter your password again</label>
<input type ="password" name="password_again" id="password_again"> 
</div>

<div class="field">
<label for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type ="text" name="name" value="<?php echo Input::get('name'); ?>" id="name"> 
</div>
<input type = "hidden" name="token" value ="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">

<input type = "submit" value ="Register">

</form>
```

**init.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(

'mysql' => array (
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'customessay',
    'db'=>'db'
    ),
'remember' => array (
    'coockie_name' => 'hash',
    'coockie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
'session' => array (
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
    )
    );
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/'. $class . '.php';
});

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
    ?>
```

**Token.php**

```
<? php
class Token {

    public static function generate(){
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');
        if (Session:exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)){
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you loading that class anywhere? I can't see it being included...

Comment: in init.php spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/'. $class . '.php';
});

Comment: I see that, but where is the $class parameter that you are loading, set to "Token" ?

Comment: I don't know :(. It is the code I took from video tutorial. I've checked it many times. I must have missed it.

Comment: The code you're showing is fine, I looked at a copy I have of it.  The problem is somewhere else, I'd suggest looking at your database file maybe

Answer (score 0):

You need register autoload function before call to class Token.
So check it and change autoload function like this.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once BASE_PATH . '/classes/'. $class . '.php';
});
```

BASE_PATH must be a constant that contains string path root of your project.
And directory "classes/" must be in root.

Function that you register will call every time when you call not loaded class.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the token and yoy does not getting in request object then you can put the given code in .htaccess file. Its does environment variable to the **value of user authentication string** to allow the string in your current request.

```
##htaccess
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```